# Showing how many permutations exist

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, permutation-cycles

Show that the number of permutations of $n$ numbers, for $n \ge 2$, with two cycles is at most $(n - 1)!(\log(n - 1)+1)$, where $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm. Justify your answer.

I assume we would use a summation at some point, but I'm unsure as to where. I have tried using notes I have made on this topic but can't seem to find anything that directly relates to this question. Could someone also explain the concept of a permutation cycle and cycle lengths as these are things I don't fully understand. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That post is very useful, thank you for linking it! However, I am unsure about how I would apply that to this question as it's log(n-1)+1 rather than just log(n). Would you be able to help with this?

Comment: Besides there is the difference of "at least" versus "at most" between the two questions.